# Should data functions be properties of a data array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a dataset and some functions that manipulate that data. I would like to store the data and functions in a logical structure that is readable and easy to use without violating good practices.

I see 2 options:

**1. Define the data as an array and add the manipulation functions to the array, which is possible because an Array is a kind of Object.**

**Example:**

```
var dataSet = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var dataSet.add = function (newData) {
    if (newData === badData) {
        console.log('bad data!');
        return;
    }
    dataSet.push(newData);
};
```

**Pros**: Cleaner, more readable, easier to use

**Cons**: We are modifying an Array object, which means it will not behave as expected, so we should not try to copy this object for example, or document the fact that doing so causes it to lose it's functions.

---

**2. Define a new Object and define the data as a property of the object along with all the manipulation functions.**

**Example:**

```
var dataSet = {
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    add: function (newData) {
        if (newData === badData) {
           console.log('bad data!');
           return;
        }
        data.push(newData);
    }
};
```

**Pros:** Object works as expected, can be duplicated easily, and packages the data and functions neatly.

**Cons:** Data cannot be referenced as a canonical representation of the object by simply calling 'dataSet'. Data Manipulation will become tedious to write in some cases, due to the need to constantly call dataSet.data instead of just calling dataSet.

Which of these 2 options is best and why? What are some examples of these options in use today?

Feel free to offer better options as well.

Edit:

Option 2a: (Use an Prototype if you have more than one dataset)

Option 3: Don't attach the data to the functions at all. Instead create a separate array for the data outside of the functions object and put all the data functions into their own object.

Thanks!

Comment: I would argue that data manipulation functions aren't part of a dataset to begin with. Just keep your data as a JSON object that you can easily fetch and store. Place your functions in a separate class that has the dataset as a property

Comment: @Kokodoko: You mean JavaScript object? JSON is a textual data format, like XML or CSV.

Comment: Yes, you convert JSON text to JS objects and back, when you save and retrieve it

Comment: @Kokodoko so in your opinion the object should not hold both data and functions?

Comment: btw, can someone explain why people voted to close this question, so I know how to ask better questions in the future?

Comment: @yosefrow It's being flagged as "primarily opinion-based", just FYI

Comment: @mhodges ah i guess that makes sense. But if nobody is allowed to ask about best practices because they border with opinion, how will people know what best practices are? Its a bit confusing to me.

Maybe, this just isnt the right place to ask about those kinds of things?

Comment: @yosefrow [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the proper place to ask about best practices, option A vs B, etc.

Comment: @mhodges cool. Thanks! :) how do i move the question then?

Comment: Neither of the two ways are elegant in JS. JS is a prototypical language. You should place your functions under the prototype of the Constructor of your data object. If you use an array for your data objects then you better add your functions to `Array.prototype` properly (through [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or best do some array subclassing

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the second option is better, cause as you said, modifying native object is a bad practice.

Actually there is a third option, you can create a `class`, that will get the native data structure and expose method on it.

In that way, you will able to create multiple instances of the same class.

```
class DataSet {
   constructor(data) {
      this.data = data;
   }

   add(newData) {
      if (newData === badData) {
         console.log('bad data!');
         return;
      }
      data.push(newData);
    }
}
```

Same implementation but with ES5

```
var DataSet = (function () {
   function DataSet(data) {
       this.data = data;
   }
   DataSet.prototype.add = function (newData) {
       if (newData === badData) {
           console.log('bad data!');
           return;
       }
       data.push(newData);
   };
   return DataSet;
}());
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to this approach if I know there will only be one instance of the dataset and its manipulations?

Comment: If you know that you will have only one instance, so i would choose you second option.

Comment: ok, btw can you please explain why option 1 is bad, even if you document the fact that it has special behavior and never copy the object?

Comment: It a matter of scale, and practice, if you write some code for you, something small, that would work, because no one will look at that code except you.
But If you work in a team, and you pass that object around, you will need to document that special function.

Comment: So basically its a bad practice to do something non-standard, if i ever plan on having someone inherit the code or work with me on the project?

Comment: Yeap, that is my opinion